# Use libcurl undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libcurl, undefined-reference

use `libcurl` to writer some test code. when try to compile, it says undefined reference. already use `-lcurl` or `-L` compile option.

```
root@ubuntu:~/work/test/curlTest# curl-config --libs
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl
root@ubuntu:~/work/test/curlTest# gcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl curl.c -o curl
/tmp/ccnFnpaW.o: In function `main':
curl.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
curl.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
curl.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
curl.c:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
curl.c:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: already tried, same result

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`-lcurl` should be put in the end of gcc command.

```
gcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu curl.c -o curl -lcurl
```

Comment: For me it was enough to simply move the -l option to the end of the command

Comment: Great, it worked for me. But I still don't know why the position of `-lcurl` matters. Why it failed before `-o` but work fine after `-o`?

Comment: It is because gcc **linking** is order-sensitive and that your *linked libraries* must follow the things that depend on.